# Bat script to run commands in a running cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I use a windows .bat script to start all of my game servers

The script looks like this:

```
cd "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop"
start Minecraft_HUB
start Minecraft_LOBBY
start Minecraft_SURVIVAL
```

with many more servers

It works for launching all of them at the same time but I need to manually type stop / exit in every single one to shut them down.
Is there any way I could have a .bat script that would insert and run a save & shut down command in a running cmd console?

I don't yet know how to make that script

Answer (score 0):

From the prompt:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2delims=," %b in ('tasklist /fo csv') do echo %~b|find /i "minecraft">nul&if not errorlevel 1 echo taskkill /pid %~c
```

As a batch-file line:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2delims=," %%b in ('tasklist /fo csv') do echo %%~b|find /i "minecraft">nul&if not errorlevel 1 echo taskkill /pid %%~c
```

Note that the `taskkill` command will merely be `echo`ed to the console. Remove the `echo` before the `taskkill` to actually execute the `taskkill`

Untested. Use at your own risk.